# Buffers sporadically not updating

Tags: debugging

I'm having a very difficult time diagnosing this problem. Essentially, *sometimes* a buffer will not update without user interaction. For example, with a terminal buffer (the shell/term/package used does not seem to matter) if I were to call some command that prints multiple lines over a period of time, say `cat long_file.txt`, I might get the entire file printed out and the buffer updates and scrolls as the file is printed or I might get the first N lines of the file and then the buffer ceases to update until I interact with that buffer (mouse click, key press, anything), or the buffer might not update at all until I interact with it.

Another example is when using a format-on-save, the file is properly formatted but the buffer is not updated to reflect this change until user input occurs.

This happens with any buffer. The includes (but is not limited to) magit, term, vterm, eshell, eat, file buffers, and dired.

This is sporadic. Sometimes it happens as soon as I open emacs, other times it might not happen for the entire duration of my usage of emacs. Most often it seems to occur at some point *after* emacs is opened.

I'm currently running a significantly minimal config in Emacs 29 to test this, but it's still happening. It doesn't seem to matter if I set any of the `auto-revert` related variables/modes or not (`auto-revert-interval`, `global-auto-revert-mode`, `global-auto-revert-non-file-buffers`).

Edit:

This is occurring in the latest 29 release of emacs-plus on a Mac M1 running Ventura 13.5.2 (but also on previous versions of Ventura). This is on GUI emacs. I have also verified this happening on the v28 and v30 of emacs-plus, the v29 of emacs-mac, and the v29 binary that the GNU project provides.

Comment: Can you provide a specific, step-by-step recipe to repro the problem, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file)? You mention a lot of things, vaguely. Even "non-file buffer" isn't very specific.

Comment: @Drew I can work on a recipe, the problem is testing that a minimum config will reproduce the issue, since I've yet to find anything specific that triggers the issue. As for the term being vague, is there a better term for a buffer that isn't tied to a file? This seems to be the term emacs uses, for example https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Non_002dFile-Buffers.html

Comment: It's about whether you can identify a *particular kind* of non-file buffer. *"sometimes a non-file buffer..."* is pretty vague. The more you can describe the problem/question specifically, the more likely you are to get useful help, I'm guessing.

Comment: I believe this is happening with any non-file buffer. Magit, term, eshell, vterm, eat, dired. Every non-file buffer I have tried has shown this problem. I'll update it to explicitly state "all non-file buffers" so it's not vague.

Comment: Is it actually "literally all buffers"?  I'm *guessing* it's nothing to do with file-visiting vs non-file-visiting and that if some code were to make edits to a file-visiting buffer without the user typing anything that this might reproduce the same issue?  (I.e. It sounds to me as if *user interaction / typing* is the point of difference, rather than file-visiting.)

Comment: Some kind of redisplay failure, perhaps?  It certainly sounds strange.  Are you running GUI or terminal frames?  Which OS?  How did you install Emacs?  Have you tried alternative builds?

Comment: @phils you might be right. The only reason I question if buffers tied to files are effected is because I use apheleia for formatting on-save and it will still update that buffer with the correct formatting, even if the non-file buffer isn't updating.

I have also updated the question with the extra details on emacs and computer.

Comment: I believe there are many options for installing Emacs on a Mac, so I would recommend testing *at least* one other besides emacs-plus.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm running emacs-plus@30 right now and have also downloaded the GNU Emacs and emacs-mac binaries. If the issue is related to emacs-plus build I'm hoping it's not in the v30 as I use a number of ns-* features that are not available outside of the Cocoa version of emacs.

Comment: I've tested now with emacs-plus versions 28, 29, and 30. I've also tested with emacs-mac and the OSX release from GNU. All tested will produce the described issue eventually. To test I've found that a long-running terminal command is ideal and have verified that once the issue crops up in that terminal buffer it will occur in all non-file buffers (tested magit, term, eshell, eat, vterm, elpaca).

Still working on a minimal config.

Comment: I've been able to determine that this is in fact _all_ buffers not merely non-file buffers. I was using apheleia to rule out buffers that have a file associated with them, however I had not considered that apheleia does some work to ensure that the point is restored to the correct place in the buffer and this is triggering the buffer update. Using a less sophisticated formater that doesn't ensure the point is restored properly will result in the buffer not updating until user input. I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: Crazy stuff.  I can't even guess at what's causing that.  Am I right in understanding that there's no issue with the *content* of the buffers, but only how they are displayed?  I.e. once a correct redisplay occurs, there is no missing or unexpected text in the buffers.  It's just that, for some reason, those windows were not being displayed correctly for a while?

Comment: I recommend that you `M-x report-emacs-bug` with all the information and testing details you have established so far.  The maintainers have deep knowledge of the display code, so you I think you want to be discussing this with them.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. Yes you're correct, the buffers are all correct (once updated).

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue, specifically with apheleia, and haven't been able to reproduce it with eshell or other non-file buffers. This happens both on Mac (emacs-plus@29), and on Linux (Emacs 29 with native Wayland). I suspected some gtk/gui redisplay issues, but it happens on a tty with `emacs -nw`.

If there's an issue filed that I can follow or add my observations, please let me know